# Tax question: W8-BEN - How to fill 2: Claim of tax treaty benefits for Indian who worked in UK for a US company and then moved to India (not working)?

Tags: united-states, india, tax-deduction, dtaa, form-w-8-ben

I am an Indian citizen worked in UK for a US company and then moved to India and not working in India for that company but has the stocks from that company.
How to fill the Part 2 in W8-BEN: Claim of tax benefits?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you think you need to claim tax treaty benefits? Claiming tax treaty benefits only makes sense if you are subject to US tax, but why do you think you would have US tax if you are not a US citizen or resident and was not working in the US?

Comment: Sold the stocks when I was in UK

Comment: But what does that have to do with the US? Why does it involve US taxes?